# Can you format a Numbers cell by calling a function?

Tags: iwork

I'd like to do something like:

```
IF(test_some_condition, BOLD(COLOR("Yes"), "#FF2222"), "No")
```

In other words, I'd like to display some text but format it differently based on some condition.  Possible?  Doesn't seem like it.

thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the formatting inspect ("Cells" pane) there is a section called "Conditional Format" in which you can change the text or background color based on the value in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only way to do this is via conditional formatting. Conditional formatting currently only uses the cell value itself, so you cannot do lookups in remote cells to determine the cell formatting, e.g. status lookups, etc.